# Error while running the app through Appium server

Tags: ios, appium

I have a problem while trying to start my session on real iOS device. I'm getting the error that is shown below:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

Logs below:

```
    [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /var/folders/bd/m3m0t_jd3snb_g5r_pg8shbc0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9957EE0F-324A-493D-8EE1-B260852D7FA3/WebDriverAgentRunner-FE9677D5-E0AF-4014-801A-185E9EA70128/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2018-06-01_154845-Mva6yb.log
[Xcode] 2018-06-01 15:48:45.818 xcodebuild[2053:230410] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/karolinablok/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-cvqckynzuuktkogfpkkkgyompmoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2129215f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
[Xcode] 2018-06-01 15:48:45.818 xcodebuild[2053:230410] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2129863c0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/karolinablok/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-cvqckynzuuktkogfpkkkgyompmoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2129215f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}}
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Testing failed:
[Xcode]     Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
[Xcode]     Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
[Xcode]     Test target WebDriverAgentRunner encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/karolinablok/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-cvqckynzuuktkogfpkkkgyompmoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2129215f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})
[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1527860925843 (15:48:45 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[XCUITest] Shutting down iproxy process (pid 2052)
[XCUITest] iproxy exited with code 'null'
[XCUITest] Successfully reset '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' with bundle id 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'
[XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device
[XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[XCUITest]     at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:427:13)
[XCUITest]     at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
[XCUITest]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[XCUITest]     at 
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1527860926254 (15:48:46 GMT+0200 (CEST))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[MJSONWP]     at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:427:13)
[MJSONWP]     at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
[MJSONWP]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[MJSONWP]     at 
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 46890 ms - 470
[HTTP]
```

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me. 
I don't know if It's a problem with Apple developer account (I have chosen my developer account yet I'm getting an error and automatic signing is also checked).

Comment: I gave answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385979/4103101

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I set up Appium for Real iOS device, Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because xcodebuild failed with code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377734/i-set-up-appium-for-real-ios-device-unable-to-launch-webdriveragent-because-xco)